# Kubernetes service external ip pending

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ip, load-balancing

I am trying to deploy nginx on kubernetes, kubernetes version is v1.5.2,
I have deployed nginx with 3 replica, YAML file is below,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-example
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and now I want to expose its port 80 on port 30062 of node, for that I created a service below,

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ils-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30062
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

this service is working good as it should be, but it is showing as pending not only on kubernetes dashboard also on terminal.
[image: Terminal output][image: Dash board status]

Answer (score 302, accepted):

It looks like you are using a custom Kubernetes Cluster (using `minikube`, `kubeadm` or the like). In this case, there is no LoadBalancer integrated (unlike AWS or Google Cloud). With this default setup, you can only use [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or an Ingress Controller.

With the [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class) you can setup a domain name which maps to your pod; you don't need to give your Service the `LoadBalancer` type if you use an Ingress Controller.

Comment: @Javier, Where in the kubernetes docs can I find how to map domain names to pods? I have a kubeadm cluster in virtualbox vms and have an nginx ingress controller (https protocol) fronting a Harbor service (http protocol) ingress within but I am unable to access the Harbor service via nginx. Reading your answer here makes me think I am missing something along these lines.

Comment: This does not really answer the quetion? The user is using `LoadBalancer` as a service type which is a valid service type. `NodePort` and `ingress` are other ways of doing it but not really solving the issue, right?

Comment: It is a valid service type but it is being used in a non-compatible platform (at least by default). In order to use LoadBalancer you must have a platform that can provide external IPs to the pods, which is something that Google Cloud or AWS do.

Comment: I am using kubeadm on AWS. Can I still `LoadBalancer`?

Comment: I think you would need to use the cloud-controller-manager in order to make it work. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/running-cloud-controller/

Comment: I'm having the same issue with https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/mysql-wordpress-pd  using Docker Edge on Mac v18.06, which as you know is not a custom cluster.  Explain that?

Comment: If you are using minikube the run "minikube tunnel". Now check your services you will get the public ip. Here is the doc for more information https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/loadbalancer/

Comment: You can also think about MetalLB which is a load-balancer provision for bare metal Kubernetes clusters via standard routing protocols. Kubernetes (not as service) fitx very well with MetalLB.

Comment: I was using docker-desktop and this was not working. I just switched to minikube and run `minikube service <service-name>` and everything went fine by just using LoadBalancer type

Answer (score 295):

If you are using Minikube, there is a magic command!

```
$ minikube tunnel
```

Hopefully someone can save a few minutes with this.

Reference link
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel

Comment: I tried `minikube tunnel` and it actually solves the `pending` issue, but then the new  external IP doesn't work: I get a timeout error...

Comment: @a.barbieri make sure you are using the tunnel ip instead of the minikube ip.  "patching ingress-nginx with IP 10.106.102.98"

Comment: yes thank you Peter. Will try. Anyway switching to Docker Desktop I've been able to overcome this issue with the out-of-the-box setting which works directly on localhost.

Comment: @a.barbieri Could you point out where those options are and what you had to set them to? I'd like to use Docker Desktop to resolve this as well, but I'm missing where and how to set this.

Comment: @user658182 I'm sorry. It's been two years since I've done this exploration with Kubernetes. I personally moved to a Docker-only solution which was more suitable for my scenario.

Comment: This one worked for me, but I had to update my minikube installation for it to work. Updated to latest, which at this time is v1.24.0

Comment: at some point minikube started supporting a LoadBalancer service. I am a complete beginner, following a kubernetes tutorial targeting digitalocean and I got it working with minikube right away (on linux) , following the "reference link" in @PeterZhou's answer.

Answer (score 109):

If you are not using GCE or EKS (you used `kubeadm`) you can add an `externalIPs` spec to your service YAML. You can use the IP associated with your node's primary interface such as `eth0`. You can then access the service externally, using the external IP of the node.

```
...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.0.10
```

Comment: There must be a missing piece of information: "externalIPs are not managed by Kubernetes and are the responsibility of the cluster administrator." (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Is there some kind of "controller" I have to install?

Comment: I'm following the Kubernetes tutorial (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/) and it worked fine with kubeadm

Comment: Thank you - brilliant, worked as expected. I've exposed Service to nodes eth network IP which is now accessible outside the cluster

Comment: Best answer, because it's the easiest and actually works. This solves the actual issue of having `EXTERNAL-IP` being stuck in `PENDING`...

Comment: I have a VM running minikube, with a specified IP address. Tying this IP to the above answer works.

Answer (score 67):

I created a single node k8s cluster using kubeadm. When i tried **PortForward** and **kubectl proxy**, it showed external IP as pending.

```
$ kubectl get svc -n argocd argocd-server
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
argocd-server   LoadBalancer   10.107.37.153   <pending>     80:30047/TCP,443:31307/TCP   110s
```

In my case I've patched the service like this:

```
kubectl patch svc <svc-name> -n <namespace> -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["172.31.71.218"]}}'
```

After this, it started serving over the public IP

```
$ kubectl get svc argo-ui -n argo
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
argo-ui   LoadBalancer   10.103.219.8   172.31.71.218   80:30981/TCP   7m50s
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention where "172.31.71.218" comes from?

Comment: @EuRBamarth I tried using all of my node's IPs in replacement to his 172.31.71.218 and they all work

Answer (score 50):

To access a service on `minikube`, you need to run the following command:

```
minikube service [-n NAMESPACE] [--url] NAME
```

More information here : [Minikube GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube)

Comment: concrete example: minikube service spark-ui-proxy --url
http://192.168.99.100:30621

Comment: This works! What does this command actually do?

Answer (score 32):

When using Minikube, you can get the IP and port through which you
can access the service by running:

```
minikube service [service name]
```

E.g.:

```
minikube service kubia-http
```

Comment: should be mentioned that service may stay in `pending` and this command gives you IP with port anyway :)

Answer (score 18):

If it is your private k8s cluster, MetalLB would be a better fit. Below are the steps.

**Step 1: Install MetalLB in your cluster**

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/metallb.yaml
# On first install only
kubectl create secret generic -n metallb-system memberlist --from-literal=secretkey="$(openssl rand -base64 128)"
```

**Step 2: Configure it by using a configmap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 172.42.42.100-172.42.42.105 #Update this with your Nodes IP range
```

**Step 3: Create your service to get an external IP (would be a private IP though).**

FYR:

Before MetalLB installation:
[image]

After MetalLB installation:
[image]

[image]

Comment: MetalLB would be a better fit than what?

Comment: For the scenario described in the original question.

Comment: I saw a MetalLB setup today for macOS using TapTun. A bit of a hack. I believe it's understood OP is using a local setup. Are you suggesting a local TapTun setup to get past the Linux hyperkit networking limitations?

Comment: Any command to get the nodes IP range?

Comment: I am playing around with MetalLB right now and installed ingress-nginx afterwards. As far as I understand it the ingress service now should have an external ip but it is still on <pending>

Answer (score 8):

Following @Javier's answer. I have decided to go with "patching up the external IP" for my load balancer.

```
 $ kubectl patch service my-loadbalancer-service-name \
-n lb-service-namespace \
-p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["192.168.39.25"]}}'
```

This will replace that 'pending' with a new patched up IP address you can use for your cluster.

For more on this. Please see **karthik's** post on [LoadBalancer support with Minikube for Kubernetes](https://blog.codonomics.com/2019/02/loadbalancer-support-with-minikube-for-k8s.html)

Not the cleanest way to do it. I needed a temporary solution.  Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 7):

If running on **minikube**, don't forget to mention namespace if you are not using default.

**minikube service << service_name >> --url --namespace=<< namespace_name >>**

Comment: Not only in minikube...

Answer (score 7):

If you are using minikube then run commands below from terminal,

```
$ minikube ip
$ 172.17.0.2 // then 
$ curl http://172.17.0.2:31245
or simply
$ curl http://$(minikube ip):31245
```

Comment: I'm using minikube and Just using nodeport + getting the minikube ip solved the issue

Answer (score 6):

Adding a solution for those who encountered this error while running on [amazon-eks](/questions/tagged/amazon-eks).

First of all run:

```
kubectl describe svc <service-name>
```

And then review the `events` field in the example output below:

```
Name:                     some-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"some-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":80,...
Selector:                 app=some
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.100.91.19
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31022/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age        From                Message
  ----     ------                  ----       ----                -------
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer    68s  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  67s  service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB
```

Review the error message:

```
Failed to ensure load balancer: could not find any suitable subnets for creating the ELB
```

In my case, the reason that no suitable subnets were provided for creating the ELB were:

**1:** The EKS cluster was deployed on the wrong subnets group - internal subnets instead of public facing. 
(*) By default, services of type `LoadBalancer` create public-facing load balancers if no `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"` annotation was provided).

**2:** The Subnets weren't tagged according to the requirements mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html#vpc-subnet-tagging).

Tagging VPC with:

```
Key: kubernetes.io/cluster/yourEKSClusterName
Value: shared
```

Tagging public subnets with:

```
Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
Value: 1
```

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is using MicroK8s: You need a network load balancer.

MicroK8s comes with metallb, you can enable it like this:

```
microk8s enable metallb
```

`<pending>` should turn into an actual IP address then.

Comment: Or if this is clear kubernetes on linux you can install MetalLB (load balancer) with some base configuration for example https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/

Answer (score 6):

A general way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service is called service in Kubernetes. There are four types of service in Kubernetes.

ClusterIP
The Service is only reachable from within the cluster.

NodePort
You'll be able to communicate the Service from outside the cluster using `NodeIP`:`NodePort`.default node port range is `30000-32767`, and this range can be changed by define `--service-node-port-range` in the time of cluster creation.

LoadBalancer
Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer.

ExternalName
Maps the Service to the contents of the externalName field (e.g. foo.bar.example.com), by returning a CNAME record with its value. No proxying of any kind is set up.

Only the LoadBalancer gives value for the External-IP Colum. and it only works if the Kubernetes cluster is able to assign an IP address for that particular service. you can use [metalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf) load balancer for provision IPs to your load balancer services.

I hope your doubt may go away.

Answer (score 4):

You can patch the IP of Node where pods are hosted ( Private IP of Node ) , this is the easy workaround .

Taking reference with above posts , Following worked for me :

kubectl patch service my-loadbalancer-service-name \
-n lb-service-namespace \
-p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Private IP of Physical Server - Node - where deployment is done "]}}'

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a bare metal you need the NodePort type
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/

LoadBalancer works by default in other cloud providers like Digital Ocean, Aws, etc

```
k edit service ingress-nginx-controller
type: NodePort

spec:
   externalIPs:
   - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

using the public IP

Answer (score 3):

**Use NodePort:**

```
$ kubectl run user-login --replicas=2 --labels="run=user-login" --image=kingslayerr/teamproject:version2  --port=5000

$ kubectl expose deployment user-login --type=NodePort --name=user-login-service

$ kubectl describe services user-login-service
```

**(Note down the port)**

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
```

**(IP-> Get The IP where master is running)**

Your service is accessible at **(IP):(port)**

Answer (score 3):

## minikube tunnel

The below solution works in my case.

First of all, try this command:

```
minikube tunnel
```

If it's not working for you. follow the below:

I restart `minikube` container.

```
docker minikube stop
```

then

```
docker minikube start
```

After that re-run `kubernetes`

```
minikube dashboard
```

After finish execute :

```
 minikube tunnel
```

Answer (score 2):

The LoadBalancer ServiceType will only work if the underlying infrastructure supports the automatic creation of Load Balancers and have the respective support in Kubernetes, as is the case with the Google Cloud Platform and AWS. If no such feature is configured, the LoadBalancer IP address field is not populated and still in pending status , and the Service will work the same way as a NodePort type Service

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
Windows 10 Desktop + Docker Desktop 4.7.1 (77678) + Minikube v1.25.2

Following the [official docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) on my side, I resolve with:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl expose deployment sito-php --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --name=servizio-php
service/servizio-php exposed
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube tunnel
 * Tunnel successfully started

 * NOTE: Please do not close this terminal as this process must stay alive for the tunnel to be accessible ...

 * Starting tunnel for service servizio-php.


PS E:\docker\apache-php> kubectl get service
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          33h
servizio-php   LoadBalancer   10.98.218.86   127.0.0.1     8080:30270/TCP   4m39s
```

The open browser on http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Answer (score 2):

Those who are using **minikube** and trying to access the service of kind `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`.

> We don’t get the external IP to access the service on the local
> system. So a good option is to use minikube IP

Use the below command to get the `minikube` IP once your service is exposed.

```
minikube service service-name --url
```

Now use that URL to serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

same issue:

> os>kubectl get svc right-sabertooth-wordpress
>
> NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
>   **right-sabertooth-wordpress**   LoadBalancer   10.97.130.7   "pending"     80:30454/TCP,443:30427/TCP
>
> os>minikube service list
>
> |-------------|----------------------------|--------------------------------|
>
> |  NAMESPACE  |            NAME            |              URL               |
>
> |-------------|----------------------------|--------------------------------|
>
> | default     | kubernetes                 | No node port                   |
>
> | default     | right-sabertooth-mariadb   | No node port                   |
>
> | default     | **right-sabertooth-wordpress** | **http://192.168.99.100:30454**    |
>
> |             |                            | http://192.168.99.100:30427    |
>
> | kube-system | kube-dns                   | No node port                   |
>
> | kube-system | tiller-deploy              | No node port                   |
>
> |-------------|----------------------------|--------------------------------|

It is, however,accesible via that http://192.168.99.100:30454.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of exposing your service
Nodeport
ClusterIP
LoadBalancer

When we use a loadbalancer we basically ask our cloud provider to give us a dns which can be accessed online
Note not a domain name but a dns.

So loadbalancer type does not work in our local minikube env.

Answer (score 0):

Delete existing service and create a same new service solved my problems. My problems is that the loading balancing IP I defines is used so that external endpoint is pending. When I changed a new load balancing IP it still couldn't work.

Finally, delete existing service and create a new one solved my problem.

Comment: Purcussive maintenance doesn't help OP understand the actual problem occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Check kube-controller logs. I was able to solve this issue by setting the clusterID tags to the ec2 instance I deployed the cluster on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on a supported cloud (aws, azure, gcloud etc..) you can't use LoadBalancer without MetalLB https://metallb.universe.tf/
but it's in beta yet..

Comment: Please provide code samples to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case best option is to use NordPort service instead of loadbalancer type because loadbalancer is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on the Docker-desktop. I just exit and turn it on again(Docker-desktop). It took few seconds, then It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all older services and creating new resolved my issue. IP was bound to older service. just try "`$kubectl get svc`" and then delete all svc's one by one "`$kubectl delete svc 'svc name'` "

Answer (score 0):

Over time, we rely on cloud vendors for networking in Kubernetes. However, when running Kubernetes on bare metal, integrating services like LoadBalancer can be more challenging.

And as others, I also got the same issue installing local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container “nodes” [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) where my services **EXTERNAL-IP** is in a **Pending** state.

My takes:

1. Install your cluster with an ingress like Istio to proxy the request (in Istio, it deploys an ingress controller that can act as a load balancer for incoming traffic).
2. The basic ad-hoc solution in NodePort/LoadBalancer service and use `kubectl proxy` (keep in mind that it can potentially expose your Kubernetes cluster to security risks, especially if it is used in an unsecured environment or by unauthorized use)
3. You can also access your pod by

> kubectl port-forward pod-name local-port:pod-port

4. Another solution for this case (On Premise clusters) will be [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) A network load-balancer implementation for Kubernetes using standard routing protocols.

When using metallb with kind we are going to deploy it in l2-mode. This means that we need to be able to connect to the IP addresses of the node subnet. If you are using Linux to host a kind cluster. You will not need to do this as the kind node IP addresses are directly attached.

A great [article](https://mauilion.dev/posts/kind-metallb/) from *Duffie Cooley* , explains the process in details

Answer (score -1):

May be the subnet in which you are deploying your service, have not enough ip's

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to do this in your on-prem cloud, you need an L4LB service to create the LB instances.

Otherwise you end up with the endless "pending" message you described.  It is visible in a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6FYtNpsT1M

You can use open source tools to solve this problem, the video provides some guidance on how the automation process should work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30355154)

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue with AWS EKS

Here how it got resolved:

> The correct tags for your Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC)
> subnets
>
> The required AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions for
> your cluster's IAM role A valid Kubernetes service definition Load
> balancers that stay within your account limit Enough free IP addresses
> on your subnets

Need to ensure following tags

```html
Key: kubernetes.io/cluster/yourEKSClusterName
Value: shared
```

```html
Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
Value: 1
```

```html
Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
Value: 1
```

**FYI, Also ensure sts is enabled for the region you are working on sts settings can be found under users, region settings.**