# Kubernetes using Gitlab installing Ingress returns "?" as external IP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab, nginx-ingress

I have successfully connect my Kubernetes-Cluster with Gitlab. Also I was able to install Helm through the Gitlab UI (Operations->Kubernetes) 
My Problem is that if I click on the "Install"-Button of Ingress Gitlab will create all the nessecary stuff that is needed for the Ingress-Controller. But one thing will be missed : external IP. External IP will mark as "?".

And If I run this command:

```
kubectl get svc --namespace=gitlab-managed-apps ingress-nginx-ingress- controller -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'; echo
```

It will show nothing. Like I won´t have a Loadbalancer that exposes an external IP.

**Kubernetes Cluster**

I installed Kubernetes through kubeadm, using flannel as CNI

**kubectl version:**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.2"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.2"}
```

Is there something that I have to configure before installing Ingress. Do I need an external Loadbalancer(my thought: Gitlab will create that service for me)?

One more hint: After installation, the state of the Nginx-Ingress-Controller Service will be stay on pending. The reason for that it is not able to detect external IP. I also modified the yaml-File of the service and I manually put the "externalIPs : -External-IP line. The output of this was that it was not pending anymore. But still I couldn't find an external IP by typing the above command and Gitlab also couldn´t find any external IP

EDIT: 
This happens after installation:
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyE03.png)

EDIT2:
By running the following command:

```
kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-ingress-controller -n gitlab-managed-apps
```

I get the following result:

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gav1U.png)

In Event log you will see that I switch the type to "NodePort" once and then back to "LoadBalancer" and I added the "externalIPs: -192.168.50.235" line in the yaml file. As you can see there is an externalIP but Git is not detecting it.

Btw. Im not using any of these cloud providers like AWS or GCE and I found out that LoadBalancer is not working that way. But there must be a solution for this without LoadBalancer.

Comment: How did you provision k8s cluster (Cloud provider, bare-metal solutions)? Can you check `kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-ingress-controller -n gitlab-managed-apps`?

Comment: @mk_sta Im running Kubernetes on a Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver) virtual machine. Check the second Image to see the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that this is an Gitlab issue. As I said above, I successfully build a connection to my cluster. Since Im using Kubernetes without cloud providers it is not possible to use the type "LoadBalancer". Therefore you need to add an external IP or change the type to "NodePort". This way you can make your Ingress-Controller accessible outside.

Check this out: [kubernetes service external ip pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending)

I just continued the Gitlab tutorial and it worked.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but it looks like Gitlab still doesnt recognize the ingress, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953914/gitlab-kubernetes-integration

Answer (score 2):

I would consider to look at [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) as for the main provisioner of Load balancing service in your cluster. If you don't use any of Cloud providers in order to obtain the entry point (External IP) for `Ingress` resource, there is option for Bare-metal environments to switch to `MetalLB` solution which will create Kubernetes services of type `LoadBalancer` in the clusters that don’t run on a cloud provider, therefore it can be also implemented for [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/).

Generally, `MetalLB` can be installed via Kubernetes manifest file or using [Helm](https://docs.helm.sh/) package manager as described [here](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/).

`MetalLB` deploys it's own services across Kubernetes cluster and it might require to reserve pool of IP addresses in order to be able to take ownership of the `ingress-nginx` service. This pool can be defined in a `ConfigMap` called `config` located in the same namespace as the `MetalLB` controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 203.0.113.2-203.0.113.3
```

External IP would be assigned to your `LoadBalancer` once ingress service obtains IP address from this address pool.

Find more details about `MetalLB` implementation for NGINX Ingress Controller in official [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#a-pure-software-solution-metallb).

Comment: Thanks! Will look about that.

Comment: Im facing a new issue. When I try to deploy something (via Gitlab) I get the following error: **$ deploy
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: no release provided
ERROR: Job failed: error executing remote command: command terminated with non-zero exit code: Error executing in Docker Container: 1** Im using the default DevOps of Gitlab. In the Build Pipeling everything works fine. But when it comes to Production I get the error code above.

Comment: Create separate question for this error, which is not connected with my answer here.