# ExternalIP for service is always pending

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have local multi machine vagrant kubernetes cluster which is created using code [here](https://github.com/ecomm-integration-ballerina/kubernetes-cluster).

I have created kubernetes replication controller created using [kubia-rc.yaml](https://github.com/luksa/kubernetes-in-action/blob/master/Chapter04/kubia-rc.yaml).

```
    vagrant@k8s-head:~$ kubectl get rc
    NAME    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
    kubia   3         3         3       26h

    vagrant@k8s-head:~$ kubectl get pods
    NAME                READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
    kubia-l28dv         1/1     Running     1          26h
    kubia-vd7jf         1/1     Running     1          26h
    kubia-wsv42         1/1     Running     1          26h
```

Then I have created the service of type LoadBalancer using this yaml [here](https://github.com/luksa/kubernetes-in-action/blob/master/Chapter05/kubia-svc-loadbalancer.yaml).

The output of the command is success and it displays successfully created service

```
    vagrant@k8s-head:~$ kubectl  get svc
    NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
    kubia                ClusterIP      10.103.199.175   <none>        80/TCP         26h
    kubia-loadbalancer   LoadBalancer   10.107.166.22    <pending>     80:30865/TCP   25h
```

The output of kubia-loadbalancer is always `<pending>` and don't know what could the issue.

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kubernetes service external ip pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending)

Comment: Vagrant isn't a public cloud provider and can't create an external IP address like that.  You should still be able to access the service through the NodePort (30865 in your example) using the Vagrant box's local IP address.