# Loadbalacing in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service

What confuses me is

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

Can some explain if this will balance load across the pods in the node? I want to, say, make 5 requests to the service of a deployment with 5 pods and want each pod to handle each request in parallel. How can I make minikube equally distribute requests across pods in a node?

Edit: There is also `--type=NodePort` how does it differ from type LoadBalancer above? Do any of these distribute incoming requests across pods on its own?

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112285/7343529 here that there is no auto loadbalancing for minikube, but then why the minikube tutorial https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service have it at first place?

Comment: minikube supports the service type `LoadBalancer` using `minikube tunnel`. But this is not the point, there is a concept called `LoadBalancer` which does not automatically load balance - it is dependant on external infrastructure. And there is the concept of a `Service` which does load balance *inside* kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service is the way to expose your deployment to external requests. Type loadbalancer gives the service an external ip which will forward your request to the deployment. The deployment defaults to round Robin (based on the docs). If you want different types of load balancing use istio or another service mesh

Comment: Is there is a way that Kubernetes itself loadbalances across pods in minikube without using any other service?

Comment: The kubernetes deployment will loadbalance between its pods. The service I am referring to is a kubernetes service (not external)https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: I feel your answer is in contrast to what i just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112285/7343529 ?

Comment: You can create a type loadbalancer also in minikube . https://metallb.universe.tf/. In any case I was explaining the concept of type loadbalancer