# How can I debug a service in K8s which get stuck on startup?

Tags: kubernetes, service

I am trying to refresh my K8s knowledge and am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/knrt10/kubernetes-basicLearning), but am running in some problems. My current cluster (`minikube`) contains one pod called `kubia`. This pod is alive and well and contains a simple Webserver.

I want to expose that server via a `kubectl expose pod kubia --type=LoadBalancer --name kubia-http`.

**Problem:** According to my K8s dashboard, `kubia-http` gets stuck on startup.

**Debugging:**

`kubectl describe endpoints kubia-http` gives me

```
Name:         kubia-http
Namespace:    default
Labels:       run=kubia
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2020-11-20T15:41:29Z
Subsets:
  Addresses:          172.17.0.5
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    <unset>  8080  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

When debugging I tried to answer the following questions:

1.) Is my service missing an endpoint?

`kubectl get pods --selector=run=kubia` gives me one `kubia` pod. So, I am not missing an endpoint.

2.) Does my service try to access the wrong port when communicating with the pod?

From my pod yaml:

```
  containers:
    - name: kubia
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

From my service yaml:

```
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32689
```

The service tries to access the correct port.

**What is a good approach to debug this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does the below command output looks like?

1. `kubectl get services kubia-http`
2. `kubectl describe services kubia-http`

Does everything looks normal there?

I think you are facing similar issue mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending).
So if `kubectl get services kubia-http` looks good except the known expected behavior `external ip pending on minikube`, you should able to access the service using nodeport or clusterip