# kubernetes service not accessible through browser

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, minikube

I am new to kubernetes and trying to deploy a simple hello-world app. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and running it on VMware workstation. I have installed minikube and trying to deploy. However, the pods are deployed but the service is not accessible through browser.

Below is my `deployment.yaml` file:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: exampleservice
spec:
  selector:
    name: myapp
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 8081
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 8080
      # Port accessible outside cluster
      nodePort: 30000
  type: NodePort
 
 
 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myappdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        name: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: pritishkapli/example:v1.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"
```

Below is the kubernetes service:

```
pritish@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
exampleservice   LoadBalancer   10.101.149.155   <pending>     8081:30000/TCP   12m
kubernetes       ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          9h
```

Below is the pods running:

```
pritish@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
myappdeployment-b85b56d64-knhhc   1/1     Running   0          17m
myappdeployment-b85b56d64-m4vbg   1/1     Running   0          17m
myappdeployment-b85b56d64-qss4l   1/1     Running   0          17m
myappdeployment-b85b56d64-r2jq4   1/1     Running   0          17m
myappdeployment-b85b56d64-tflnz   1/1     Running   0          17m
```

Please help!

PS: I have updated the `deployment.yaml` file and it's working as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes service external ip pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### **TL;DR**

This is not the issue with the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` but the **mismatch between `service.spec.selector` value and `deployment.spec.selector.matchLabels`** value.

---

#### How you can fix your setup?

To fix your setup you can use the same values from either `Service` or `Deployment`.

**Please choose only one of the following options:**

- `deployment.yaml` changes:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myappdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: myapp # <-- CHANGES
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp # <-- CHANGES
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: pritishkapli/example:v1.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"
```

- `service.yaml` changes:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: exampleservice
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp # <-- CHANGES
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 8081
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 8080
      # Port accessible outside cluster
      nodePort: 30000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

---

#### How could you tell that this was the issue with `selector`?

This comes down to the experience on working with Kubernetes, but the easiest method to check it is by either (using old examples):

- `kubectl describe service exampleservice` (part of this output is redacted due to readability)

```sh
Name:                     exampleservice
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Selector:                 app=myapp
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.8.10.103
Port:                     <unset>  8081/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30000/TCP
Endpoints:                <none> # <-- LOOK HERE!
```

- `kubectl get endpoints exampleservice`

```
NAME             ENDPOINTS   AGE
exampleservice   <none>      2m3s
```

As you can see on above output there are no `endpoints` to send the traffic to (`Pods`).

---

#### Service of type `LoadBalancer` on `minikube`

Talking from the perspective of the `Service` of type `Loadbalancer` on `minikube`:

The easiest method would be to connect as said previously by a `NodePort`. Due to `minikube`'s local nature, it won't get the `External IP` assigned unless you opt for a workaround including for example:

- `minikube tunnel`

> **tunnel** - creates a route to services deployed with type LoadBalancer and sets their Ingress to their ClusterIP. for a detailed example see https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/loadbalancer
>
> *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Commands: Tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/)*

---

**A side note!**

I haven't tested it personally but you could try to experiment with: `$ minikube addons enable metallb` to assign it the IP address in the same `CIDR` as your `minikube` instance and then query (`curl`) this newly assigned IP.

A guide for more reference:

- *[Medium.com: Faun: Metallb configuration in minikube to enable Kubernetes service of type Loadbalancer](https://medium.com/faun/metallb-configuration-in-minikube-to-enable-kubernetes-service-of-type-loadbalancer-9559739787df)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Access application cluster: Create external load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)*
- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Start](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)*

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am using the `type: NodePort`. I have updated the yaml files in my question section. Please confirm if I am doing it right.

Comment: @Pritish as I can see the `YAML` manifests that you've included are correct. You should be able to communicate with your app by: `minikube_ip:nodeport`.

Comment: Thanks Dawid. I am now able to communicate with the app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deployment your service with type loadbalance as your cluster dot not set loadbalancer. Try deploy your service with type NodePort or clusterIP

Comment: Thanks. But, I am still not able to access in my browser. Minicube IP: `192.168.49.2`. I am trying this url in my browser: `192.168.49.2:30000`. Am I doing it right ?

Comment: More informantion [publish service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

Comment: I am sorry. Didn't quite understand after going through the link. Is there something to be done in my yaml file ? Got below output:
`pritish@ubuntu:~/kubernetes/exampleapp$ curl http://192.168.49.2:30000`
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 30000: Connection refused`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it took me a whole day to figure it out, for me the reason was unable to access the pods from the outside is because the EXTERNAL IP is none when you ran "kubectl get svc" **The external ip**: is what you need to access the cluster from the outside. and the reason the external IP is none is because your type is type: NodePort, change it to type: LoadBalancer.type Loadbalancer is what directs traffic from the outside the cluster (internet) to the pods in the cluster. I **think** the NodePort is within the cluster so your service.yaml file should look like this.

```js
 ---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: exampleservice
spec:
  selector:
    name: myapp
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 8081
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 8080
      # Port accessible outside cluster
      nodePort: 30000
  type: LoadBalancer
```