# ambassador service stays "pending"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ambassador

Currently running a fresh "all in one VM" (stacked master/worker approach) kubernetes `v1.21.1-00` on Ubuntu Server 20 LTS, using

- cri-o as container runtime interface
- calico for networking/security

also installed the kubernetes-dashboard (but I guess that's not important for my issue ). Taking this guide for installing ambassador: https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/install/yaml-install/ I come along the issue that the service is stuck in status "pending".

`kubectl get svc -n ambassador` prints out the following stuff

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ambassador         LoadBalancer   10.97.117.249    <pending>     80:30925/TCP,443:32259/TCP   5h
ambassador-admin   ClusterIP      10.101.161.169   <none>        8877/TCP,8005/TCP            5h
ambassador-redis   ClusterIP      10.110.32.231    <none>        6379/TCP                     5h
quote              ClusterIP      10.104.150.137   <none>        80/TCP                       5h
```

While changing the `type` from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort` in the service sets it up correctly, I'm not sure of the implications coming along. Again, I want to use ambassador as an ingress component here - with my setup (only one machine), "real" loadbalancing might not be necessary.

For covering all the subdomain stuff, I setup a wildcard recording for pointing to my machine, means I got a CNAME for `*.k8s.my-domain.com` which points to this host. Don't know, if this approach was that smart for setting up an ingress.

Edit: List of events, as requested below:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  116s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ambassador/ambassador-redis-584cd89b45-js5nw to dev-bvpl-099
  Normal  Pulled     116s  kubelet            Container image "redis:5.0.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    116s  kubelet            Created container redis
  Normal  Started    116s  kubelet            Started container redis
```

Additionally, here's the service pending in yaml presenation (exported via `kubectl get svc -n ambassador -o yaml ambassador`)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    a8r.io/bugs: https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/issues
    a8r.io/chat: http://a8r.io/Slack
    a8r.io/dependencies: ambassador-redis.ambassador
    a8r.io/description: The Ambassador Edge Stack goes beyond traditional API Gateways
      and Ingress Controllers with the advanced edge features needed to support developer
      self-service and full-cycle development.
    a8r.io/documentation: https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/
    a8r.io/owner: Ambassador Labs
    a8r.io/repository: github.com/datawire/ambassador
    a8r.io/support: https://www.getambassador.io/about-us/support/
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"a8r.io/bugs":"https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/issues","a8r.io/chat":"http://a8r.io/Slack","a8r.io/dependencies":"ambassador-redis.ambassador","a8r.io/description":"The Ambassador Edge Stack goes beyond traditional API Gateways and Ingress Controllers with the advanced edge features needed to support developer self-service and full-cycle development.","a8r.io/documentation":"https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/","a8r.io/owner":"Ambassador Labs","a8r.io/repository":"github.com/datawire/ambassador","a8r.io/support":"https://www.getambassador.io/about-us/support/"},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"ambassador-service","product":"aes"},"name":"ambassador","namespace":"ambassador"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","port":80,"targetPort":8080},{"name":"https","port":443,"targetPort":8443}],"selector":{"service":"ambassador"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-05-22T07:18:23Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: ambassador-service
    product: aes
  name: ambassador
  namespace: ambassador
  resourceVersion: "4986406"
  uid: 68e4582c-be6d-460c-909e-dfc0ad84ae7a
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.107.194.191
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.107.194.191
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 32542
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32420
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    service: ambassador
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

EDIT#2: I wonder, if https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112285/667183 applies for my process as well?

Comment: Can you do describe: `kubectl describe pod ambassador -n ambassador` and post the events at the bottom you would find them?

Comment: After completely removing & redeploying ambassador, I got the following events.

Comment: the pods seem to have started normally, I believe there is definitely something you can see in the description of the pending svc.?

Comment: Again: is the `type: LoadBalancer` correct here? Or do I need an external lb (that not equals this ambassador instance) for it?

Comment: Type Loadbalancer is fine, even I'm having the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is pretty much here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1064313/ambassador-service-stays-pending . After installing a `load balancer` the whole setup worked. I decided to go with `metallb` (https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/#installation-by-manifest for installation). I decided to go with the following configuration for a single-node kubernetes cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 10.16.0.99-10.16.0.99
```

After a few seconds the load balancer is detected and everything goes fine.