# GlooEdge testing routes using glooctl

Tags: kubernetes, routes, gloo

Anyone worked with solo.io's glooctl command.  I was working on the hello world example, https://docs.solo.io/gloo-edge/latest/guides/traffic_management/hello_world/

and everything went smoothly until the last step, testing the route rule:

bash % curl $(glooctl proxy url)/all-pets

which returns, "Error: load balancer ingress not found on service gateway-proxy
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"

I tried putting what I thought was Gloo's "proxy url":

```
bash% curl $(glooctl gloo-system-gateway-proxy-8080)/all-pets
```

and bash%   curl $(gloo-system-gateway-proxy-8080)/all-pets
Error: unknown command "gloo-system-gateway-proxy-8080" for "glooctl"

So it doesn't like logical commands like "proxy url" and it doesn't
take the actual proxy url.

Anyone fought this battle and won?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I use minikube, the problem is that `EXTERNAL-IP` is in `pending` state.

`minikube tunnel` solve the problem.

`glooctl proxy url`

`Error: load balancer ingress not found on service gateway-proxy`

`kubectl get svc -n gloo-system`

```
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
gateway         ClusterIP      10.102.152.223   <none>        443/TCP                               49m
gateway-proxy   LoadBalancer   10.102.171.136   <pending>     80:30439/TCP,443:32178/TCP            49m
gloo            ClusterIP      10.97.145.90     <none>        9977/TCP,9976/TCP,9988/TCP,9979/TCP   49m
```

> https://makeoptim.com/en/service-mesh/kubernetes-external-ip-pending
> [Kubernetes service external ip pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command is `curl $(glooctl proxy url)/all-pets;` what does `glooctl proxy url` return for you?

Answer (score 0):

The solution @northmorn provided works just fine, and the command on minikube is as simple as `minikube tunnel`. Thanks @Northmorn.