# Can't get UDP packets to my container in kubernetes [MiniKube]

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, udp, minikube

I'm new to Kubernetes, but have managed to build myself a container that runs perfectly directly under Docker and also seems to run up fine in a k8s deployment.

The container is an implementation of a couple of UDP packet replicators from github installed on Ubuntu.

When it's running directly under Docker on my machine, I can send UDP packets to the container and have them replicated back to different ports on my machine proving that the replication works. (Sending and receiving the packets with `netcat`).

However, I think I am missing something in the k8s networking side of things.

I am using MiniKube on my machine and I am using the following k8s manifest to create the deployment with just one container.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: samplicator-deployment
  labels:
    app: samplicator
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: samplicator
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: samplicator
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: samplicator-container-01
        image: dgbes/udp-fan-out-tools:latest
        command: ["samplicate"]
        args: ["-p3160","192.168.1.159/3161","192.168.1.159/3162"]
        ports:
        - name: receiver
          protocol: UDP
          containerPort: 3160
```

I then create the deployment with: `kubectl apply -f create-samplicator-deployment.yaml`

I then set up a couple of UDP listeners with `netcat` on my host machine with `nc -ulk -p 3161` and `nc -ulk -p 3162`.

If I then connect to the running container with `kubectl exec --stdin --tty samplicator-deployment-{randomPodName} -- /bin/bash` and manually use `netcat` send packets to my host machine I can see those arriving no problem.

I find the container/pod IP address with `kubectl get pod -o wide`.

When I try to send a packet to the samplicator process in the pod, though, I see nothing coming back to my host machine.

So, I then spawned a shell in the container/pod, checked that the samplicator process was running correctly (it was), and installed `netcat` in the container instance.

Using `netcat -u {my host machine IP} 3161` I can send packets from the container to my host machien and they are received no problem.

So, it seems that the issue is getting the packets TO the container.

I confirmed this by running `nc -ulk -p 3600` in the container shell and sending a packet from my host to that port in the container - nothing is received in the container.

I am aware that the ports need to be exposed on the container and that 'services' are used for this, but I thought that that was what the `ports:` section in the template spec of the deployment was doing.

That didn't create a service to expose the port, so I added a service definition to the end of my deployment manifest YAML as follows:

```
---
apiVersion: v1       
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: samplicator-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: samplicator
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: receiver-service
    protocol: UDP
    port: 3160
    targetPort: 3160
```

I'm obviously missing something here, and my apologies if my k8s terminology is a bit mangled - as I say I'm completely new to k8s.

Any pointers to how to correctly make that UDP port reachable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

Service `type=LoadBalancer` doesn't work with MiniKube as it relies on an external cloud service apparently.

I noticed that my service was sat in a `pending` state with the `ExternalIP` never being allocated, which lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54265229/2211491).

The magic being to simply run the following command in a separate terminal window which then allowed the external IP to be allocated to the service.

```
minikube tunnel
```

Once that was run and the `ExternalIP` allocated, sending packets to that ExternalIP works perfectly.